# Verificar o fim da música e executar macro

Tags: vba, userform

Olá, estou fazendo uma mesa de som virtual para um evento e gostaria de dar o efeito de clicado do botão. Estou fazendo mega simples, porem preciso que o botão fique apertado enquanto a musica toca e quando esta acabar o botão desaperte.

Está assim:

```
Private Sub CAMPAINHA_Click()

CAMPAINHA.Visible = False

WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\SONS\CAMPAINHA.mp3"

CAMPAINHA.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Esta é a mesa normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim eu gostaria que ela ficasse enquanto toca a musica e no fim voltasse ao normal.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma resposta boa tambem:

```
Private Sub WindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange()

    If WindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = wmppsMediaEnded Then

        CAMPAINHA.Visible = True
        VOZA1.Visible = True
        VOZALEA1.Visible = True
        VOZALEB1.Visible = True
        VOZB1.Visible = True
        VOZA2.Visible = True
        VOZALEB2.Visible = True
        VOZB2.Visible = True
        VOZA3.Visible = True
        VOZB3.Visible = True
        VOZB4.Visible = True
        SOM_AMBIENTE.Visible = True
        SOM_AMBIENTE2.Visible = True
        SOM_CINEMA.Visible = True
        SOM_FOTO.Visible = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Quando o áudio chegar no fim todos ficam visíveis.

Answer (score 1):

Uma das maneiras seria pegar o tempo de duração do arquivo mp3 que será tocado e colocar o Excel em *pausa* durante esse tempo para quando finalizar, retorne o botão para o cor padrão.

1. Para pegar os dados de um arquivo mp3 pode usar a seguinte macro:

   ```
   Function FileInfo(path, filename, item) As Variant
   Dim objShell As IShellDispatch4
   Dim objFolder As Folder3
   Dim objFolderItem As FolderItem2

       Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
       Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(path)
       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(filename)
       FileInfo = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, item)

       Set objShell = Nothing
       Set objFolder = Nothing
       Set objFolderItem = Nothing
   End Function
   ```
2. A partir daí pode chamar essa função buscando os dados, exemplo:

   ```
   Range("A1").value = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 20) 'Artista
   Range("A2").value = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 14) 'Album
   Range("A3").value = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 21) 'Título
   Range("A4").value = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 26) 'Sequencia (Track#(
   Range("A5").value = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 16) 'Genero
   Range("A6").value = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 27) 'Duração
   ```
3. Então creio que no meio de sua macro ficaria algo assim:

   ```
   Sub aoApertarBotao()

   Dim mp3Duration as String

       'Altera a cor do botão para modo "tocando"
       '[...] seu código para tocar a música

       mp3Duration = FileInfo("C:\Caminho\do\Arquivo\mp3\", "nome da musica.mp3", 27)
       Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(mp3Duration))

       'Altera a cor do botão para modo padrão

   End Sub
   ```

Veja se consegue assim!

Fontes/Créditos:

1. http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/mp3_file_lister/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time-excel-vba

Comment: É um bom método, mas achei o `WindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange` coloque um `If WindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = wmppsMediaEnded Then` e funcionou muito bem. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado.

Comment: Legal, poste sua resposta com o código para referência futura e marque sua resposta como resposta válida para auxiliar outros que virão.